# Is there a possibility to lag values of a data frame in r indexed by time?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lag

My questions concerns lagging data in r where r should be aware of the time index. I hope the question has not been asked in any further thread. Lets consider a simple setup:

```
df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c("1990-01-01","1990-02-01","1990-01-15","1990-03-01","1990-05-01","1990-07-01","1993-01-02")), value=1:7)
```

This code should generate a table like

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1990-01-01 | 1 |
| 1990-02-01 | 2 |
| 1990-01-15 | 3 |
| 1990-03-01 | 4 |
| 1990-05-01 | 5 |
| 1990-07-01 | 6 |

And my aim is now to try to lag the "value" by e.g. one month such that e.g when I try to compute the lagged value of "1990-05-01" (which would be 1990-04-01 but is not present in the data) should then generate an NA in the specific row. When I use the standard lag function r is not aware of the time index and simply uses the value "4" of 1990-03-01 which is not what I want. Has anyone an idea what I could do here?

Thanks in advance! :)

All the best,

Leon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `%m-%` for lagged month like below

```
library(lubridate)
transform(
  df,
  value_lag = value[match(date %m-% months(1), date)]
)
```

which gives

```
        date value value_lag
1 1990-01-01     1        NA
2 1990-02-01     2         1
3 1990-01-15     3        NA
4 1990-03-01     4         2
5 1990-05-01     5        NA
6 1990-07-01     6        NA
7 1993-01-02     7        NA
```

Comment: This is a really nice idea. Thank you. :) But do you also have an idea how to proceed if I have multiple columns? So that I do not have to code each column manually?

Comment: @Leon Could you show an example with multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

For an example with multiple columns lets consider:

```
df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c("1990-01-01","1990-02-01","1990-01-15","1990-03-01","1990-05-01","1990-07-01","1993-01-02")), value=1:7, value2=7:13)
```

I recently found myself the following solution:

```
df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(across(2:ncol(df), .fns= function(x){x[match(date %m-% months(lags),date)]}, .names="{.col}_lag"))
```

Thanks to your code @ThomasisCoding. :)